# Filtering 0 or null values in two column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a output data as shown below

query used : `select * from table 1`

table 1

```
name  a   b
pen   0   50
paper 10   0
bike   0   0
candy  0   0 
disk   20  30
```

the output should be

```
name  a   b
pen   0   50
paper 10   0
disk   20  30
```

should eliminate the record with both a = 0 and b = 0

If I use the filter condition as

```
select * 
from table1 
where a!=0 and b!=0
```

then I am getting only `disk`

Comment: `where (a,b) <> ((0,0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
WHERE a != 0 OR b != 0  -- get records with at least one of [a, b]
```

If you happen to have NULL values in those columns they will be excluded just like 0 would (because `NULL != 0` evaluates to false).

Comment: Could filter through `null` using `OR IS NOT NULL`. Example  `select * from receipts
where delivery_date IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: @Justplayit94 Don't over-complicate things. If `a` is `NULL`, `a != 0` won't evaluate as true.

Comment: @Thilo Your answer mentions that it won't work with NULL values, but that's not right, it will handle them just fine. You can remove that notice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    NOT (coalesce(a, 0) = 0 AND coalesce(b, 0) = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting only `disk` with your where-clause is the `AND` you used. `AND`means that both conditions must be true, so column a must not be 0 **and** column b must not 0.

Only when this condition is met, a result is shown. In your example only the `disk` dataset meets the condition.

To achieve what you want use an `OR` instead.

In order to filter `NULL` values you can check for `IS NULL` like this:

```
WHERE (a <> 0 AND a IS NOT NULL) OR (b <> 0 AND b IS NOT NULL)
```